# Module in Maven project that is not included in a certain profile is still being built

Tags: maven, multi-module

I haven't had any issues using profiles in maven until now. We recently added a new module `newModule` to our maven project, and it's building when we run a profile it's not included in.

We have 2 profiles, `default` and `coverage`. Our `mainModule` has dependencies on `backendModule` and `newModule`, neither are included in our coverage profile, but one of them is building when we run that profile.  Our maven profiles look something like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>coverage</id>
        <modules>
            <module>mainModule</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>mainModule</module>
            <module>backendModule</module>
            <module>mainModuleTools</module>
            <module>newModule</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

When I use `mvn clean install` all 4 modules in our default profile are built. When I use `mvn clean install -Pcoverage`, both `mainModule` and `newModule` are being being built.

Is there a time where a module not listed in a profile is included in the build?

Comment: If you like to build only parts of your reactor you should use `mvn -pl mainModule clean package` or `mvn -pl backendModule -amd` etc. [Don't use profiles to activate/deactivate modules](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/11/09/why-is-it-bad-to-activate-slash-deactive-modules-by-profiles-in-maven/)

Comment: That won't work for our project. mainModule has 6 aggregator submodules, and each of those have anywhere from 2 to 8 modules themselves. Using `-pl mainModule` will not build its child modules. Using `-amd` builds all modules since mainModule depends on them.  

I'm looking to solve why this new module is being included in the build of `-Pcoverage` what is causing maven to build it?